# how to return mongodb documents directly to client, using Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Given documents with datetime and data to be displayed in a graph, how can I return the query results directly without converting from BSON to Ruby and then finally to JSON?

Problem: The time values are stored correctly for the client in BSON, but having Ruby involved turns it into Time objects that I have to do `time.to_i * 1000` to store correctly in the returned JSON. In any case, I have no need to transform any of the data, so this just feels like a waste.

I run Rails, Mongoid on Heroku + MongoHQ. I'd like to leave the Rails app doing the authorization of the query, but not converting the response to Ruby objects.

```
def show_graph
  raw_bson = TheModel.all_raw_documents_matching(query_params)
  raw_bson.to_json  
  # Alternatively, this BSON to JSON could be happening client side. 
  # side. Whatever, just don't convert to ruby objects...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has many point of view. 
Instead of BSON deserialization i see more critical how the `to_json` method handles the serialization of `Date` and `Time` ruby object.

The most easy, and tricky way that comes in my mind is to override the `as_json` method of `Time` class:

```
class Time
 def as_json(options={})
    self.to_i * 1000
 end
end

hash = {:time => Time.now}
hash.to_json # "{\"a\":1367329412000}"
```

You can put it in an initializer. This is a really easy solution but **you have to keep in mind that every ruby `Time` object in your app will be serialized with your custom method.** This could be fine, or not, it's really hard to say, some gem could depend on this, or not.

A more secure way is to write a wrapper and call it instead of `to_json`:

```
def to_json_with_time
  converted_hash = self.attributes.map{|k,v| {k => v.to_i * 1000 if v.is_a?(Time)} }.reduce(:merge)
  converted_hash.to_json
end
```

Finally if you really want to override the way how Mongoid serialize and deserialize your object and if you want skip the BSON process you have to define `mongoize` and `demongoize` methods.
Here you can find the documentation: [Custom Field Serialization](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#custom_fields)

#### **UPDATE**

Problem is serialization not deserialization. If you get a raw BSON from a query you still have a string representation of a `Time` ruby object.
You can't convert BSON directly to JSON because it's not possible to convert a string representation of time, to an integer representation without passing from ruby `Time` class.

Here an example how to use Mongoid Custom Field Serialization.

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :bar, type: Time
end


class Time

  # The instance method mongoize take an instance of your object, and converts it into how it will be stored in the database
  def mongoize
    self.to_i * 1000
  end

  # The class method mongoize takes an object that you would use to set on your model from your application code, and create the object as it would be stored in the database
  def self.mongoize(o)
    o.mongoize
  end

  # The class method demongoize takes an object as how it was stored in the database, and is responsible for instantiating an object of your custom type.
  def self.demongoize(object)
    object
  end

end

Foo.create(:bar => Time.now) #<Foo _id: 518295cebb9ab4e1d2000006, _type: nil, bar: 1367512526> 
Foo.last.as_json # {"_id"=>"518295cebb9ab4e1d2000006", "bar"=>1367512526}
```

Comment: this is ruby objects, exactly what I'm asking to avoid.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide an example. Hope could help you.

Comment: I see the raw time in MongoDB using mongo console is `"updated_at" : ISODate("2012-10-26T06:47:27.603Z") `. Your answer is "you can't return directly, each value must be a ruby object". Not the answer I'm looking for. Still, interesting approach, store the value as you'd like to retrieve it as (integer millis in this case). I would never hack Time like that, but I get the idea.